# How do we check if the current page is loaded from the sidemenu in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 page which can either be accessed when the user clicks on a link in the sidenav or by default it's active when the app is loaded. However, when accessed through a click on the side-nav I want to do add some extra feature.

How can I specifically know if the currently active page has been accessed by clicking on the side-nav
I have tried

```js
openPage(page: any) {
    data = {fromSidenav:true};
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component,{data});
  }
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a parameter would be the best way, but the right way to do it is

```
openPage(page: any) {
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component, { fromSidenav: true });
}
```

And then in the other page, get that parameter like this:

```
export class MyClass{
 constructor(public navParams: NavParams){
   let fromSideNav = this.navParams.get('fromSidenav');
 }
}
```

Comment: That works. actually, this is not so different with what I was doing earlier which I realised later that it was actually working.